Valid positions of `alignas` inside a plain array definition
I'd like to understand the validity of different alignas specifier position within a plain array definition:
constexpr std::size_t Required=16;

alignas(Required) int iarr1[10]; // 1
int alignas(Required) iarr2[10]; // 2
int iarr3 alignas(Required) [10]; // 3
int iarr4 [10] alignas(Required); // 4

2 is ignored by gcc with a warning.
2 and 4 give plain errors with clang LIVE.
This answer explains why 1 is correct, but does not cover the other cases and I'd like to understand what other forms might be valid.
According to me:

2 may be wrong because alignas will be parsed as part of the type (int) declaration and it cannot apply to types as clang and gcc report (thus, acceptance by msvc would be a bug).
3 may be correct because its a simple-declaration; int is forming de decl-specifier-seq while iarr3 alignas(Required) [10] seems a valid noptr-declarator consisting of a noptr-declarator+attribute-specifier which itself is a noptr-declarator followed by [] forming again a noptr-declarator which, ultimately can be interpreted as an * init-declarator-list*.
4 may be correct following the same line of reasoning (switching [] and the attribute-specifier still form a noptr-declarator); yet it is rejected by clang.

What analyses are (in)correct and why?

For the record, the running snippet linked above:
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    constexpr std::size_t Required = 16;

    alignas(Required) int iarr1[10];

#if defined(__GNUG__)
    int iarr2[10];
#if defined(__clang__)
    std::cout << "clang rejects int alignas(Required) iarr2[10];\n";
#else
    std::cout << "gcc ignore int alignas(Required) iarr2[10]; with warning\n";
#endif
#else
    int alignas(Required) iarr2[10];
#endif

    int iarr3 alignas(Required)[10];

#ifndef __clang__
    int iarr4[10] alignas(Required);
#else
    std::cout << "clang rejects int iarr4[10] alignas(Required);\n";
    int iarr4[10];
#endif

    std::cout << iarr1 << '\n';
    std::cout << iarr2 << '\n';
    std::cout << iarr3 << '\n';
    std::cout << iarr4 << '\n';
}


C++ should not be learnt by trial and error. Have you tried finding what the standard says about this?

@user12002570 yes I did but couldn't find (for instance in N4861, 9.12.2)

I see. I've explained a similar case in this answer of Why doesn't alignas compile when used in a static declaration with clang?

@user12002570 in order to help me follow your answer, alignment-specifier is a special case of attribute-specifier?

Grammatically yes, as mentioned in the comment to the answer there.

@user12002570 hum, from your linked answer I can follow why 1 is OK but I cannot follow a same line of reasoning for the other cases (for instance I would have rejected 2 but all compilers accept it.

@user12002570 shouldn't iarr2 alignas(Required) [10] be rejected also?  AFAIU, the [ cannot be separated from its declarator-id?

Yes, compiler bug.

@user12002570 in the light of these comments (and the ones in your linked answer) don't you think it might be worth to reopen the question and reorient it towards how the different forms (don't) match the grammar and possible compilers bugs?

It is clear these are compiler bugs. And as there is already a language-laywer answer that explains this, there is no need to reopen this. I would instead file compiler bug reports on their official sites.

@user12002570 digging into the grammar, I would have thought that int iarr alignas(Required) [10]; or int iarr [10] alignas(Required); would be valid. They both decompose as simple-declaration = decl-specifier-seq (int) + declarator; the declarator being a noptr-declarator[N]. This can be followed by an optional attribute-specifier-seq (2nd case, the declarator being a simple id). the noptr-declarator before [N] can also be an id followed by an attribute-specifier-seq (first case). Only the first case is accepted seamlessly by all compilers.

alignas can only be applied to variables, non-static data members, and classes ([dcl.align]/1, [dcl.attr.grammar]/5).
In the example you give:

1 applies the alignment specifier to iarr1 ([dcl.pre]/4),
2 applies it to the type int ([dcl.spec.general]/1),
3 applies it to iarr3 ([dcl.meaning.general]/1),
4 applies it to the array type int[10] ([dcl.array]/3).

Thus, 1 and 3 are well-formed, while 2 and 4 are ill-formed.

could you elaborate on the 4th case? I can't get it right with grammar rules to why a postfix alignas would apply to the array type and not the variable name?

@Oersted The attribute-specifier-seq in the 4th case is part of an array noptr-delcarator; the fact that it appertains to the array type is stated in [dcl.array]/3.
